# Sveltekit Package generated types are not recognized by TypeScript

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I just tried packaging and consuming a new NPM package for Svelte that contains a single UI component.  The source is [here](https://github.com/webJose/svelte-htable).

I followed all recommendations, at least to the best of my knowlege, found in the [Packaging](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging) document for **SvelteKit**.

While the package compiles and uploads to NPMJS, it does not function when consumed.

I got the following error in the VS Code interface:

> Argument of type 'typeof import("c:/(blah blah)/node_modules/svelte-htable/dist/index")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConstructorOfATypedSvelteComponent'.
> Type 'typeof import("c:/(blah blah)/node_modules/svelte-htable/dist/index")' provides no match for the signature 'new (args: { target: any; props?: any; }): ATypedSvelteComponent'.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Running into the same problem myself. Curiously I have one repo where things work well, and another with the same packages that doesn't. What version of Sveltekit are you using? What have you tried? I'm trying to use `svelte-portal` and `svelte-intersection-observer`, both of which ship with type declarations. I even checked the node_modules. Tried creating an index.d.ts in the root to declare the class (both top-level and within a `declare module`). No luck.

Comment: For reference I confirmed your package produces the necessary type definition files, so I don't think the issue is with the sveltekit package generation. Rather it's probably how it's consumed. https://hyrious.me/npm-browser/?q=svelte-htable@0.1.0/package/package.json

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because TypeScript is not able to locate the generated types. To fix this, you can add a paths property to their tsconfig.json file, which maps the module name to the actual file location.

Here is an example paths property that the user can add to their tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "types/generated/*": ["src/types/generated/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

This tells TypeScript to look for any module starting with types/generated/ in the src/types/generated/ directory.

After adding this paths property, the user should be able to import the generated types like this:

```
import type { MyType } from 'types/generated/blah';
```

Note that we use import type instead of just import because we are only importing the types, not any runtime values.

Comment: Can't speak for the OP, but I'm getting this issue when importing a svelte component directly. So we're trying to import a value, not a type. It's that TypeScript isn't finding the associated types for that value. Also, it looks like in the OP's referenced package (and the one's I installed), the types are right next to the original svelte files not in a `types/generated` folder. However I tried your suggestion just in case and it didn't work. Even tried adding the exact type file to the `includes` field of the `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Magno, thanks for stopping by.  I think this is not the path.  I'll post an answer, but it won't really be an answer, I think.

Comment: Uh. I see. Well... I will left it here just for the case the people to knows what didn't worked and not lost time. Thanks for pointing.